# AngularJS $scope in loops/forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach, angularjs-scope

I am writing an app that will allow the user to click on a location and be directed to google maps, everything works as it should except: In this app I have a table that I want to be able to be sorted by Distance from the user or by Name, However, I am having trouble getting the distance to display. I am using the Haversine formula to calculate the distance to the location. I have tested the formula with fixed coordinates and the formula is not the problem. I believe the problem lies in the longer `forEach` with `getCoordDistance();` and `location.Distance = d;` at the bottom. I am getting an error saying that `$scope.myLat`,`$scope.myLon`,`$scope.locLat`, and `$scope.locLon` are not defined, then I also get this odd error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at getCoordDistance (http://run.plnkr.co/NDFxGL6q55m1601d/script.js:32490:21)
    at http://run.plnkr.co/NDFxGL6q55m1601d/script.js:32469:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.q [as forEach] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:7:280)
    at new <anonymous> (http://run.plnkr.co/NDFxGL6q55m1601d/script.js:32459:11)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:34:479)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:35:103)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:66:467
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:53:250
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:7:386)
```

here is my code: 
JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.ASiteLocs = [{
    "name": "IL5077 BRUSSELS",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.58543899999999,38.955472,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5076 KAMPSVILLE",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.661923,39.29403,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5146 CARROLLTON",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.39965700000001,39.309142,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5153 GREENFIELD",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.208747,39.364077,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "MO2766 BRIGHTON",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-90.14174300000001,39.038493,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5221 QUINCY INDUSTRIAL",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-91.41167299999999,39.912781,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5010 QUINCY",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-91.407062,39.937277,0"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "IL5010P QUINCY",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": "-91.407062,39.937277,0"
    }
  }];
  $scope.SSiteLocs = [/*contains more locations*/];
  $scope.SiteLocs = $scope.SSiteLocs.concat($scope.ASiteLocs);
  repoSortOrder = "site.name";
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
  function GetLocation(location) {
    $scope.myLat = location.coords.latitude;
    $scope.myLon = location.coords.longitude;

  }


  angular.forEach($scope.SSiteLocs, function(object) {
    object.carrier = 'Sprint';
  });
  angular.forEach($scope.ASiteLocs, function(object) {
    object.carrier = 'AT&T';
  });

  angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location) {
    var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;
    if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength - 2, clength) === ",0") {
      location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0, clength - 2).split(",");
      Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0];
      Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1];
      Com = ",";
      location.Point.coordinates = Lon.concat(Com, Lat);
      $scope.locLat = location.Point.coordinates[0];
      $scope.locLon = location.Point.coordinates[1];
      getCoordDistance();
      location.distance = d;
    }
  });

  function getCoordDistance() {
    Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
      return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    var lat2 = $scope.myLat;
    var lon2 = $scope.myLon;
    var lat1 = $scope.locLat;
    var lon1 = $scope.locLon;

    var R = 3959; // Mean Earth radius in miles 
    var x1 = lat2 - lat1;
    var dLat = x1.toRad();
    var x2 = lon2 - lon1;
    var dLon = x2.toRad();
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    $scope.d = R * c;
  }
});
```

and HTML if it matters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="google-maps@1.0.0" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script data-require="geo-location-javascript@*" data-semver="0.4.8" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geo-location-javascript/0.4.8/geo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>ECC</title>
  </head>

  <body link="white" vlink="white">
    <center>
      <h1>Site Lookup</h1>

      <div>{{site.carrier}}</div>
      <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" border="1" placeholder="Please enter site name..." />
        <select placeholder = "Sort by..." ng-model="repoSortOrder">Sort by
          <option value="site.name">Name</option>
          <option value="site.distance">Distance</option>
        </select>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Distance</td>
              <td>Carrier</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="site in SiteLocs | orderBy:'repoSortOrder' | filter : search">
              <td>
                <a ng-href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{site.Point.coordinates}}">
            {{site.name}}
            </a>
              </td>
              <td>{{site.distance}} Miles</td>
              <td>
            {{site.carrier}}
          </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you declare the `toRad` method in the `getCoordDistance` function but you call this method AFTER trying to use the `toRad` method. 
So when you want to call it, the toRad method is not defined yet.

EDIT:

Comment: the toRad function work only with the number and the coordinates are not.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit further please? @polochon

Comment: you declare the toRad method in the getCoordDistance function but you call this method AFTER trying to use the toRad method.
So when you want to call it, the toRad method is not defined yet.

Comment: So should I move toRad outside of getCoordDistance?

Comment: yes just move the 

    Number.prototype.toRad declaration directly

into the core of your controller

Comment: That didnt work but I believe the problem is that toRad only works with numbers and the coordinates are strings.

Comment: ... and i missed that.. ^^ great, you can simply parse your coordinate with the Number function,   `Number(x1)`

Comment: would I parse the coordinates like this: `myLat = parseInt(location.coords.latitude)` or another way?

Comment: you can use Number(location.coords.latitude)

Answer (score 1):

Try and define it like this:

$scope.getCoordDistance = function () { ... }

And define the function before you call it in the forEach.
(call it with $scope.getCoordDistance())

Comment: Solid effort, but no dice. Any other ideas?